# A sequence $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ while rolling a die

Tags: probability

We roll the dice infinitely many times. What is the probability that we get the sequence $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ infinitely many times?

I thought about using Bernoulli trials, but I don't get any results.

Comment: What is the probability that from now on, this sequence never appears again?

Comment: check also the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem)

Comment: Infinite times is so much... probability is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P=1$. Let's say a "trial" consists of rolling a die $6$ times. Say $p>0$ is the probability that any individual trial has outcome $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$. Call that a "good" trial; anything else is "bad".

The probability of $N$ bad trials in a row is $(1-p)^N$, which tends to $0$. So the probability of at least one good trial is $1$. Now start over after your first good trial; the probability of another good trial later is also $1$...

Answer (score 2):

Are you rolling one infinite sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ and looking at subsequences, or rather rolling infinitely many sequences of length 6? Regardless, the probability will be 1. For fixed $k$, the probability $P(E_k)$ of the sequence occurring at most $k$ times in the first $n$ terms will tend to 0 as $n \to \infty$. Since $E_1 \subseteq E_2 \subseteq \dots$ we conclude $P(\bigcup_k E_k) = 0$, hence the complement of this union (sequence occurring infinitely many times) must have probability 1.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm no expert in probability, but wouldn't any given sequence of numbers appear an infinite amount of times? This seems related to the infinite monkey theorem, I think you should read up on that to get an answer to your question. I know that the probability of getting this sequence in 6 rolls is $\frac{1}{6^6}=\frac{1}{46656}$ so with an infinite number of rolls, we can expect this to happen an infinite number of times, with each occurrence happening approximately once for every 46656 trials.